# Llenar ArrayList sin que se repitan los valores

Tags: java

Buenas soy nuevo aquí en esta página. Mi problema es el siguiente (aunque estoy seguro que será sencillo para ustedes):

Yo  tengo un `ArrayList` con una cantidad de *n* vendedores que se pueden o no repetir, pero yo quiero pasar dichos vendedor a otro `ArrayList` sin que estos se repitan.

Por ejemplo, si en el ArrayList vendedor tenemos:

```
{ Pedro, Lucas, Juan, Jose, Pedro, Robinson, Jose, Lucas }
```

o sea, repetidos; en el ArrayList2 debe estar:

```
{ Pedro, Lucas, Juan, Jose, Robinson }
```

sin repetir.

Aquí tengo el código con el que intento hacerlo pero no funciona como yo quiero, ya que al ejecutar solo muestra Robinson y Jhon.

```
public class Testings {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Vendedor> vendedor = new ArrayList<Vendedor>();
    ArrayList<Vendedor> juntados = new ArrayList<Vendedor>();

    vendedor.add(new Vendedor("Robinson", 0, 0, 0));
    vendedor.add(new Vendedor("Jhon", 0, 0, 0));
    vendedor.add(new Vendedor("Robinson", 0, 0, 0));
    vendedor.add(new Vendedor("Pedro", 0, 0, 0));
    vendedor.add(new Vendedor("Juan", 0, 0, 0));
    vendedor.add(new Vendedor("Cristian", 0, 0, 0));
    vendedor.add(new Vendedor("Pedro", 0, 0, 0));
    vendedor.add(new Vendedor("Cristian", 0, 0, 0));
    vendedor.add(new Vendedor("Juan", 0, 0, 0));

    boolean user = false;

    for (int u = 0; u < vendedor.size(); u++) {

        if (juntados.size() <= 0) {

            juntados.add(vendedor.get(u));

        } else {

            for (int y = 0; y < juntados.size(); y++) {

                if (vendedor.get(u).getNombre().equals(juntados.get(y).getNombre())) {

                    user = true;

                }

            }

            if (user == false) {

                juntados.add(vendedor.get(u));
            }

        }

    }

    for (Vendedor indice : juntados) {

        System.out.println(indice.getNombre());

    }

}

}
```

Comment: podrias implementar la interface set, ya que no permiten elementos duplicados.
Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Hay una forma mucho más sencilla de hacer el filtrado de elementos en la cual dejamos que java se encargue de todo :D

Una vez que tenes tu lista 'vendedor' poder crear un HashSet a partir de ella:

```
  Set<Vendedor> miHashSet = new HashSet<>(vendedor);
```

Los Set son una colección que no admiten duplicados, por lo tanto vas a obtener el resultado que queres sin necesidad de filtrar a mano.
Despues podes seguir trabajando con el Set o en caso de necesitar una lista podes hacer lo mismo pero al reves

```
  List<Vendedor> juntados = new ArrayList<>(miHashSet);
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Solo añadir, que si la versión de java utilizada te lo permite, es preferible usar tipos genéricos, es decir `Set<Vendedor>` en lugar de simplemente `Set` por tres motivos: mayor robustez en tiempo de compilación para inferir los tipos, minimizar el uso de casting y facilitar la implementación de métodos genéricos: Más info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: Tenes toda la razón. Modificado, gracias por el aporte :D

Answer (score 0):

Un pequeño fallo: debes reinicializar `user` a `false` antes de buscar el vendedor `u` en la lista de `juntados`.

Como no lo reinicializas a `false`, una vez que encuentra la primera coincidencia lo pones a `true`, ya nunca más lo cambias y descartas todos los otros valores.

En todo caso aconsejo que te familiarices con el depurador de Java, que te permite ir ejecutando el programa línea a línea y ver el valor de las expresiones, de forma que puedes ver dónde el programa deja de hacer lo que esperas.

Comment: Pues si, pero el depurador no me ABRE no sé por que, se abre el menu  del depurador, pero se cierra al instante, asi que acudí  a esta pag para que me ayudasen porque el depurador no me funciona. muchas gracias funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu clase vendedor necesitas generar los hashcode and equals methods(los IDES los pueden generar de manera automática).

Luego aplicando un poco de programación funcional...

```
    juntados = (ArrayList<Vendedor>) vendedor.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```